# A problem of a linear ODE with order $n$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there an algorithm to solve this EDO in $\mathbb{R}$?

\begin{equation}
x^{(n)}(t) + x^{(n-1)}(t) + \cdots + x''(t) + x'(t) + x(t) = 0
\end{equation}

Or a more general ODE:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kx^{(k)}(t) = f(t)
\end{equation}

With $\{a_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sucession belonging to $\mathbb{R}$. I don't how to start.

Comment: This is probably the most "standard" $n$-th order ODE. Why is it weird?

Comment: @ArcticChar You are right, fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common method for linear ODE like this is to assume that the solution takes the form $y(t) = e^{\lambda t}$.  This will give you a polynomial in $\lambda$, the solutions of which are called the eigenvalues.  The solution will be something like
$$y(t) = c_1e^{\lambda_1 t}+c_2e^{\lambda_2 t} + ... + c_ne^{\lambda_n t}.$$
For any complex $\lambda$, you will have some portion of your solution being sinusoidal.  You also need to adjust your solution for any repeated $\lambda$.